# How can I make a "Table" where rows wrap horizontally in HTML5 /css3?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following table using html table, tr, td tags. 
[image]

This is all great, but I am using angular, and the problem is if I have more rows, I don't have the space for it vertically. Instead I want to "overflow" to the right of it so that it looks like:

[image]

What is the best way using HTML5/CSS so that I can make it such that content spills over if it exceeds the table? Note that in some cases I may have 2 or 3 entries, so I am hoping I don't have to make the width double the size of normal at the start, and instead have the table be sized based on the number of entries I have in the table. No scrollbars.

I feel like the table tag in HTML is limiting and may not allow me to do this. What is the best way to do this? Using divs?

```
<table style="background:green;">
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Sport</td><td>Score</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr>
</table>
```

Attempting a flexbox approach, though it seems that if I put the flexbox in a div, then the background doesn't appear to fill properly once the entries go beyond the first column:

https://jsfiddle.net/t0h7w2hw/

Comment: what's about flex? you can set the `display` for the trs

Comment: flex could be an hint, but tricky https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GmdMMa , why don't you rethink your template ? none of your code won't help you to be helped .....

Comment: I am not sure if flex can actually help with the dynamic resizing based on the number of rows. I could be wrong, would love to see a sample that shows what I am trying to show in my graphic. Right now, I just have a table with tr tds... which flat out does not do anything like I am describing, which is why I am looking for something smarter...

Comment: Why don't you use `div`s and media queries?

Comment: @fubar can you show what it would look like? thought flexbox could handle this sort of thing. If div is the est way to go, am fine with that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is all great, but I am using angular, and the problem is if I
>   have more rows, I don't have the space for it vertically.

What has angular got to do with any of this?

> [..] if I have more rows, I don't have the space for it vertically.
>   Instead I want to "overflow" to the right of it

Tables won't give you that kind of flexibility especially, you won't be able to control height and flow of the rows as columns.

> [..] so that I can make it such that content spills over if it exceeds the
>   table? Note that in some cases I may have 2 or 3 entries, so I am
>   hoping I don't have to make the width double the size of normal at the
>   start, and instead have the table be sized based on the number of
>   entries I have in the table.

One simple and quick way could be to split your rows into tables of their own. If you can have that structure, then it is simply a matter of [using CSS `columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Typically, you would wrap all these tables in a `div` which will have its `height` constraints. Set `column-*` properties on the wrapping `div` and there you go. You may play around with `column-gap`, `column-rule`, `column-span`, and `column-fill` properties to beautify the whole thingy.

Also note that you will need to use `break-inside: avoid` on the tables to avoid them breaking half-way while flowing to the next column.

**Example Snippet:**

```css
#rowflow {
  height: 120px; max-height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #d33; overflow: hidden;
  column-width: 200px; column-gap-width: 0px; column-fill: auto;
  column-rule: 1px solid #bbb; 
}
table { 
  font-family: sans-serif; margin-bottom: 2px;
  table-layout: fixed; width: 190px; 
}
table:first-child { column-span: all; }
table, th, td { border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid gray; padding: 6px; }
table, tr { break-inside: avoid; }
th, td { text-align: left; }
th:last-child, td:last-child { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<div id="rowflow">
  <table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Sport</th><th>Score</th></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Jordan</td><td>Soccer</td><td>50</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

---

In the above snippet, the wrapping `div` is height constrained and you can see the columns flowing.

**[Use this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n73dcqno/)** to try changing the window size and see the effect.

> [..] so I am hoping I don't have to make the width double the size of
>   normal at the start, and instead have the table be sized based on the
>   number of entries I have in the table. No scrollbars.

The wrapping `div` will be full-width on its own. However, you can twiddle with `overflow` to control how the overflow is handled. Changing width dynamically based on the width of the content is a whole different ball-game altogether where you would need JavaScript and it gets messy.

**Note:** For the above example to work, you will need to fix the widths of your tables so that the columns align neatly. You may use `table-layout: fixed` to use a fixed layout.

Answer (score 8):

Please follow below code example

This will wrap rows in a list style in mobile. 
You need to data-label attribute with each content td so that it knows which column it is. In mobile you can show lable before td by using css content:"" property.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Statement Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Card</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Card">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Card">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Card">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Card">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">02/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
      <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The issue with this, is that this does not wrap to the right with a height limit. My question is explicitly looking for fixed height table implementation where if a new entry is added, it wraps to a new column to the right of it.

Comment: Now your scenario is different. i checked you have edited you question. Any ways. i will create a new reply and post it here. thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no such facility is defined for HTML table element by using CSS. I have tries some by giving various positions for table and containing div, not worked. As in the fiddle example you have provided, you must use HTML div element for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
//HTML

<div ng-app>
  <div class=" header-row">
    <div class="col">Name</div>
    <div class="col">Sports</div>
    <div class="col">Score</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="rows in chunkedData">
      <div class="span4" ng-repeat="item in rows">
        <span class="col">{{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="col">{{item.sport}}</span>
        <span class="col">{{item.score}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


//Script

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      name : '0',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    },
    {
      name : '1',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    },
    {
      name : '2',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    },
    {
      name : '3',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    },
    {
      name : '4',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    },
    {
      name : '5',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    },
    {
      name : '6',
      sport: 'Cricket',
      score: 89
    }
  ];
  $scope.chunkedData = chunk($scope.data, 3);
  function chunk(arr, size) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
      newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
    }
    return newArr;
  }
}

//CSS

.col{
  display: inline-block;
  width:70px;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
}
.header-row{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
}
.row{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left; 
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

JsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32296/

You simply need to create a chunk of records for first column which you can do in the controller itself and then with the help of ng-repeat you can render it

Answer (score 2):

Using `div` and `column`

```css
.columns {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.myTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.myHeader {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.myCell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="myTable">
    <div class="myHeader">
      <div class="myCell">Name</div>
      <div class="myCell">Sport</div>
      <div class="myCell">Score</div>
    </div>
    <div class="myCell">Bob</div>
    <div class="myCell">Soccer</div>
    <div class="myCell">8</div>
    <div class="myCell">Jane</div>
    <div class="myCell">Softball</div>
    <div class="myCell">9</div>
    <div class="myCell">Hank</div>
    <div class="myCell">Baseball</div>
    <div class="myCell">6</div>
    <div class="myCell">Lisa</div>
    <div class="myCell">Soccer</div>
    <div class="myCell">9</div>
    <div class="myCell">Bill</div>
    <div class="myCell">Football</div>
    <div class="myCell">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/b690cL2r/)